# Hyperledger fabric 2.0 : Chaincode commit fails with the error ' chaincode definition not agreed to by this org'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to learn HLF 2.0 chaincode lifecycle, my network configuration as follows

1. Two orgs with one peer each
2. RAFT as ordering service(total 3 orderes)

Following the official doc to install the chaincode https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/deploy_chaincode.html

when I try to commit the chaincode getting the following error

```
Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'CommitChaincodeDefinition': chaincode definition not agreed to by this org (LeftOrgMSP)
```

however when i check the commitreadyness

```
{
    "approvals": {
        "LeftOrgMSP": true,
        "RightOrgMSP": false
    }
}
```

i got the `LeftOrgMSP` as true

**UPDATE**

command for approving org

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o  orderer1.base.order:7050 --channelID basechannel --name fabcar --version 1.0 --package-id $CC_PACKAGE_ID --sequence 1 --tls \
--cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.base.order-cert.pem
```

command to commit

```
peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer1.base.order:7050 --channelID basechannel \
 --name fabcar --version 1.0 \
 --sequence 1  --tls true \
 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/base.order/orderers/orderer1.base.order/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.base.order-cert.pem \
 --peerAddresses peer1.base.left:7051  \
 --tlsRootCertFiles   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/base.left/peers/peer1.base.left/tls/ca.crt
```

Comment: Are you committing the chaincode with the same sequence and version that you approved?

Comment: Yes the versions are same @laharris i have updated my commands

Comment: This issue would whenever not installed and approved the chaincode on the current peer. please check queryinstalled chaincode. If not please install that chaincode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The overall process to deploy chaincode is 4 steps:

1. Package the chaincode
2. Install it on your org peers - in your case LeftOrg and RightOrg
3. Approve the chaincode definition for your organization, and
4. Commit the chaincode definition to your channel.

Install - When you installed the chaincode, did you install it on both orgs?  If so, a successful install will return the package identifier (ID), which is a combination of the package label (fabcar_X), combined with a hash of the chaincode package.  I am assuming that's what you have stored in $CC_PACKAGE_ID, confirm if the value is accurate.

After a successful install, query the peer for installed chaincodes to see if the result matches.  The cmd is:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
```

Approve & Check Commit Readyness - The purpose of Commit Readyness is to help you verify that enough channel members have approved a chaincode definition to meet the endorsement policy (a majority by default) before the definition can be committed to a channel. It looks like you've only approved the chaincode for LeftOrg, you still need to approve it for the RightOrg (Although your log message seems to say otherwise, so there might be more to it).  I would execute the approve for RightOrg and then check commit readiness on both orgs to confirm.

Follow that up with commit

And, if the commit was successful, confirm that the definition committed successfully on both orgs with

```
peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted
```

I have a [blog on medium on chaincode deployment](https://medium.com/murgai-emergingtech/finally-hyperledger-fabric-made-easy-with-a-new-test-network-iv-e11f82d906ec) if you want more information.

Comment: Now i got the commitreadyness  true but committing the chaincode i m getting the same error(chaincode definition not agreed to by this org (LeftOrgMSP))

Comment: Thank you for this. For some reason my brain thought I had to commit the chaincode from both peers, which you of course don't!